# program to provide a simple class for modeling the flight of projectiles

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that represents a simple class for modeling the flight of projectiles and returns the max height and distance traveled.  Here is what I have so far:

```
th import sin, cos, radians

class Projectile:
    """Simulates the flight of  simple projectiles near the eath's surface, ignoring 
wind resisitance.  Tracking is done in two dimensions, height(y) and distance(x)."""

    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, height):
        """Create a projectile with given launch angle, initial velocity and height."""

        self.xpos = 0.0
        self.ypos = height
        theta = radians(angle)
        self.xvel = velocity * cos(theta)
        self.yvel = velocity * sin(theta)

        #Find time to reach projectiles max height.
        self.th = self.yvel/9.8

    def update(self, time):
        """Update the stat of this projectile to move in time seconds farther into its flight"""

        self.xpos = self.xpos + time * self.xvel
        yvel1 = self.yvel - 9.8 * time
        self.ypos = self.ypos + time * (self.yvel + yvel1) / 2.0
        self.yvel = yvel1
        self.maxpos = max(self.maxypos, self.ypos)

    def getY(self):
        """Returns the y position (height) of this projectile."""

        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        """Returns the x position (distance) of this projectile."""

        return self.xpos

    def getMaxHeight(self):
        """Returns the max height of the projectile."""

        return self.maxypos

    def getInputs():
        a = eval(input("Enter the launch angle (in degrees): "))
        v = eval(input("Enter the inital velocity (in meters/sec): "))
        h = eval(input("Enter the inital height (in meters): "))
        t = eval(input("Enter the time interval between position calculations:"))
        return a, v, h, t

def main():
    angle, vel, h0, time = getInputs() 
    elapsedTime = 0.0
    cball = Projectile(angle, vel, h0)
    cball.getInputs()
    while cball.getY() >= 0:
        cball.update(time)
        elapsedTime + time
    print("\nDistance traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getX()),
          " in {0:0.1f} seconds.".format(elapsedTime))
    print("\nMaximum height traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getMaxY()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I am missing something in main() as it keeps telling me that 'getInputs' is not defined and for the life of me I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: def blocks inside the class are unindented.

Answer (score 1):

When your indentation is corrected, it works; at this moment, your getInputs() function is likely indented to in a way that locates it inside your class.
The line `cball.getInputs()` is redundant.
`eval` on user raw input is not a good idea, arbitrary code could be executed.

Generally, it is not a good idea to mix i/o with business logic. Your class should not harbor i/o; keeping `getInputs()` as a function is better.

```
from math import sin, cos, radians


class Projectile:
    """Simulates the flight of  simple projectiles near the eath's surface, ignoring
    wind resisitance.  Tracking is done in two dimensions, height(y) and distance(x)."""

    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, height):
        """Create a projectile with given launch angle, initial velocity and height."""

        self.xpos = 0.0
        self.ypos = height
        theta = radians(angle)
        self.xvel = velocity * cos(theta)
        self.yvel = velocity * sin(theta)

        #Find time to reach projectiles max height.
        self.th = self.yvel/9.8
        self.maxypos = float('-inf')

    def update(self, time):
        """Update the stat of this projectile to move in time seconds farther into its flight"""

        self.xpos = self.xpos + time * self.xvel
        yvel1 = self.yvel - 9.8 * time
        self.ypos = self.ypos + time * (self.yvel + yvel1) / 2.0
        self.yvel = yvel1
        self.maxypos = max(self.maxypos, self.ypos)

    def getY(self):
        """Returns the y position (height) of this projectile."""

        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        """Returns the x position (distance) of this projectile."""

        return self.xpos

    def getMaxY(self):
        """Returns the max height of the projectile."""

        return self.maxypos

def getInputs():
#     a = float(input("Enter the launch angle (in degrees): "))
#     v = float(input("Enter the inital velocity (in meters/sec): "))
#     h = float(input("Enter the inital height (in meters): "))
#     t = float(input("Enter the time interval between position calculations:"))
#     return a, v, h, t
    return 1, 2, 3, 4

def main():
    angle, vel, h0, time = getInputs() 
    elapsedTime = 0.0
    cball = Projectile(angle, vel, h0)
    while cball.getY() >= 0:
        cball.update(time)
        elapsedTime + time
    print("\nDistance traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getX()),
          " in {0:0.1f} seconds.".format(elapsedTime))
    print("\nMaximum height traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getMaxY()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `getInputs` is supposed to be a method of the projectile class.

Comment: No, why would you think that? If you look in main, `getInputs()` is not called on an object.

Comment: Because `cball` is an instance of the class. and he calls `cball.getInputs()`.

Comment: good point; this line is redundant and not necessary; it must be deleted.

Comment: so should it be just getInputs() and not cball.getInputs()?

Comment: Yes, that is what it "should be"; this design is preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Okay so I have made those changes and now I get "AttributeError: 'Projectile' object has no attribute 'maxypos' ".

Comment: Yes, `self.maxypos` is not defined in your code; you must define it.

Comment: `self.getMaxY` was not defined either... I corrected it

Comment: Yes, I caught that one and it now works.  Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `self` as a parameter in `getInputs`. It should be

```
def getInputs(self)
```

and then you can call it with `cball`.

Edit: the above suggestion would make `cball.getInputs()` work.

But as mentioned in the comment, the other solution would be to move getInputs() out from the Projectile class, in which case you would not pass 'self' as parameter.

Comment: Thank you.  It is not liking the line  "angle, vel, h0, time = getInputs()" what do I have wrong here?

Comment: You're using getInputs() as both an instance method of Projectile (when you call cball.getInputs()) and as a function in the global scope of your program (like main() ) .  But the latter doesn't exist, i.e., you don't have a function getInputs(), just the Projectile instance method, which happens to have the same name. I would suggest moving getInputs() outside of the Projectile class -- its logic does not rely on any data from a Projectile instance. That way you can replace the `cball.getInputs()` with `getInputs()` -- just like you do in the first line of main().

Comment: This comment contradicts your proposed answer.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque yes, I thought the question at first was how to fix the cball.getInputs() line. If my suggestion is followed, then 'self' would need to be removed.